# Error using gcloud command in Python script running as Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have below python code running in Google Cloud function.

```
pname = format(os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT'))
project_metadata_file = "/tmp/" + pname + "_proj_metadata.json"
bucket_name = "XXXX"
H = open(project_metadata_file, "w")
project_list_command = "gcloud projects describe " + pname + " --format json"
project_output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(project_list_command))
project_output_json = json.loads(project_output)
H.write(project_output_json)
H.close()
upload_blob(bucket_name, project_metadata_file, os.path.basename(project_metadata_file))
return pname
```

Here is the error I am getting from the Cloud function. Could you please advise how can I have gcloud as a requirement for this cloud function. Please advise.

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcloud': 'gcloud'
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you're going to have a very hard time trying to get a fully configured instance of gcloud deployed with your code.  You might want to look into calling Google Cloud APIs directly instead.

Comment: Yes to @doug-stevenson answer. Please don't do this! You're trying to spawn a process running gcloud from a python process running as a cloud function. What you should do is use Google's Cloud Client Libraries for the functionality that you need. Here's the relevant library that underpins `gcloud projects describe`: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-resource-manager/

Comment: Thank you Doug/DazWilkin for your inputs..I am trying to get the project metadata like(key:values) pairs defined on the project and don't see any API provided in cloud-resource-manager to pull this info. So I had reverted using the gcloud projects describe shell command....the other option I found to pull project metadata was using compute engine API's which I don't want to use as I not standing up a compute instance in my project.

Comment: Sorry...never mind..i was able use to Method: projects.get API provided by cloud resource manager and was able to retrieve the tags...earlier was using fetch_project method which was not giving all the info. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expect your function as being deployed into a container that includes, in your case, a Python runtime. You can not assume that your cloud function includes a shell environment with cloud sdk installed. I would recommend using [Method: projects.get API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/get?apix_params=%7B%22projectId%22%3A%22wave25-vladoi%22%7D). In case you want to use the cloud sdk commands then Google Cloud Run would be one of the solutions.

Enter the project name and you will receive this output:

```
{
  "projectNumber": "",
  "projectId": "",
  "lifecycleState": "",
  "name": "",
  "createTime": "",
  "parent": {
    "type": "",
    "id": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marian..yes, cloud run is an option in my case...was wondering if I can some how have cloud function container running my python function have a dependency on Cloud SDK

Comment: No, your cloud functions can not have a dependency on Cloud SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As DazWilkin already mentioned, your code will be much cleaner and robust if you use specialized library.

If you really need to use Cloud SDK with your function, you can achieve it with the following.

1. [Download the appropriate archive](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives#installation_instructions).
2. Extract it to your function's folder
3. Set path to gcloud command to './google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud' in the code. This may vary depending on where you extracted SDK in your function folder.
4. Deploy function with either gcloud command or zip it and deploy from Console.

Comment: Thank you Emil..will give it a try